# Absolute center a fluid div

Tags: css

Good day.

I know that if you want to absolute center a div, you do this:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="child">blahblah</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent{
   width: 500px;
   height: 500px;
   position: absolute; /*(or relative)*/
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-top: -250px;
   margin-left: -250px;
   text-align: center;
}
```

What if the parent div is a fluid div? How do you ABSOLUTE center it meaning:

```
#parent{
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
  top: 50%; ->is this right?
  left: 50%; -> is this right?
  margin-top: ???;
  margin-left: ???;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Is your #parent actually the child of the element your positioning to>?

Comment: the #parent div is the child to the body, or whatever div is its parent...depending on position relative or absoulte

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5SSD/ Like this?

Comment: Don't think you understood my question - You are providing me with a fixed with element. How do you do absolute positioning on a fluid element? - where the fluid element has a max-width/height limit?

Comment: By fluid, do you mean centering a div, when the parent float and may resize (responsive)?

Comment: yes, exactly Bertrand

Answer (score 0):

As the `width` and `height` are fluid, you need to go with javascript or jQuery. Just add the below code in `head` tag. (*The below example is in javascript*)

```
<script>
   window.onresize = function(){
      //To work even on resize
      getToMiddle();
   }
   window.onload = function(){
      getToMiddle();
   }

   function getToMiddle(){
      var box = document.getElementById('parent');
      var height = box.offsetHeight;
      var width = box.offsetWidth;
      box.style.top = -(height/2);
      box.style.left = -(width/2);
   }
</script>
```

---

and your css would be something like this:

```
#parent{
   max-width: 500px;
   max-height: 500px;
   background-color:green;
   position:absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
  /* width: 10%;
   height: 10%; */
}
```

**To test, give `width: 10%; and height: 10%`**

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/ewizad/7/edit)**

Comment: Thanks but in your fiddle only the width resizes, only the height...and the text inside the box is not contained inside when resizing...

Comment: @DavidVanStaden Give also `min-width` and `min-height`. Something like this in this fiddle http://jsbin.com/ewizad/10/edit

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with CSS alone.

```
#parent {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

See demo https://jsfiddle.net/matharden/8kmvt8qd/

Answer (score 0):

I'll simply use `flex` to achieve this...

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">blahblah</div>
</div>
```