# Vertical centering of an element with CSS (margin-top, top)

Tags: css

To horizontally center an element, one sets width to `x`, left to `50%` and margin-left to `-x/2`. This works perfectly with `x = 50 %` (see example below). Why does it not work for vertical centering? The example below does not work.

```css
div.myDiv {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -25%;
    margin-top: -25%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">I'm a div</div>
```

Tested in FF10 and IE8 with HTML 4.01 Transitional and only one div-tag in the body-section.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10010055/1312610   Go to this page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have fixed width and height (fluid). So you can't make the div in center vertically just using the CSS you mentioned in your post. You need to go with javascript or jQuery to achieve that. I have done this before, so I am just linking it here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15293191/1577396

---

As specified in [**W3C**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties), the `margin` properties including `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` refers the **width** of the containing block (not the *height*), if set in `percentages`.

So, you can't align a fluid container vertically using `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` as the case in fixed dimension container.

Comment: Thanks. I thought so, but why is not possible? And why do both IE and FF support it for horizontal centering but not for vertical centering?

Comment: @user1904159 the margin values always refer to the width of the containing block if set in `percentages`. So, not possible to verical aligning as the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` should consider `height` inspite. check this link http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. :) Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

Vertical centering can be done in css playing with `display: table-cell` or fiddling with `line-height` - just a starting point for you to play with

Comment: It can also be done just like the OP has it except the `<div>` needs fixed dimensions

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
div.myDiv {
margin: 0 auto;
}

auto will get you the horizontal centering you are looking for OR you can just set auto for the entire myDiv to get both vertical and horizontal centering.

div.myDiv {
margin:auto;
}
```