# Align element using its child element

Tags: html, css

Structure of HTML is the following:

```
<div id="c1">
  <div id="c2">
    <div id="d1"></div>
    <div id="d2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want #c2 to be aligned vertically inside #c1 in such a way that #d2 verticaly centered inside #c1.
Here is clarifying picture:
[image]

It is OK if it will only works in latest Chrome. Thanks.

**UPD**: Heights of #d1 and #d2 are not fixed. Distance between #d1 and #d2 is fixed.

**UPD2**: You can forget about #c2. I want #d1 and #d2 to be placed one after another and #d2 to be centered in #c1.

Comment: You can use css 'margin' property.

Comment: Do you know is any height of the boxes fixed?

Comment: Do you mean to align center #c2 horizontally and #d2 vertically?

Comment: @dzhioev Per the update, what if height#d1+height#d2+distance exceeds the "middle" portion of #c1? Is #c1 auto height?

Comment: Check this [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15293191/1577396) might help you.

Comment: @Passerby, #c1 has fixed heigth and it's enough to place elements as I described.

Comment: @Mr_Green, I want to avoid using JS.

Comment: @dzhioev I am sure what you are trying to achieve is not possible using pure css.

Comment: @dzhioev Me, too. I've thought through relative & absolute position, starting from bottom, negative margins, but I don't see a possibility, because, you want to grow from center vertically into two directions. And that's IMHO not possible in CSS only.

Comment: @dzhioev To cheat it: http://jsfiddle.net/cyZcH/2/ :)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML** :

```
<div id="c1" style="height:200px;width:250px;">
    <div id="c2" style="height:150px;width:210px;">
        <div id="d1" style="height:50px;width:100px;"></div>
        <div id="d2" style="height:50px;width:100px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
div{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding:5px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Check the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyZcH/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:midddle` on parent div

```
#c1{
    display:table-cell;
    border:red solid 1px;
    width:600px;
    height:300px;
     vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center
}
#c2{
    border:green solid 1px;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto

}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7tvxM/1/)**

Comment: Your solution is wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/7tvxM/2/ -- as you can see #d2 not centered.

Comment: @dzhioev R u new to html/css?? Updated demo here http://jsfiddle.net/7tvxM/3/. I thought you can do that by taking reference of parent div.

Comment: And I hope you don't need vertical middle alignment to #c2, if not remove  display:table-cell and vertical-align:midddle. http://jsfiddle.net/7tvxM/4/

Answer (score 0):

So finally I've found solution by myself. It only works for Chrome because of "-webkit-*" properties, but I think it can be easily adopted for any modern browser. The main idea is to use transform, because transform can refer (by using percentage) to sizes of element itself, not to its parent's sizes. CSS looks like:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid;
}

#c1 {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
}

#c2 {
    width: 350px;
    position: relative;
}

#d1 {
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: -20px; /* distance between #d1 and #d2 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
}

#d2 {
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hRsJY/)